# How to install and use a project template using dotnet CLI

Tags: command-line, powershell, visual-studio, .net-framework, c#

I recently made a [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/csharp/comments/ut36r5/disabling_autoloading_of_default_namespaces_in/) in which I was asking about how to disable implicit usings in Visual Studio 2022. From that post I understood a couple of things:

- This can only be done per project basis using the `.csproj` file by not including the `ImplicitUsings` tag
- It is possible to export a template of such a project and reuse it in other projects using `dotnet`.

Since I am interested in generating customized console applications directly from the command line (Powershell, to be specific), I first exported my adjusted console app as a template using the Visual Studio 2022 UI under *Project > Export Template > Project template*. This generated a `.zip` file which was dumped in a generic Templates folder in the Visual Studio installation directory.

According to the [link](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/custom-templates) in the reddit post, it should be possible to then make use of this template using `dotnet new --install` and then `dotnet new template`.

I have tried the following obvious commands:

`dotnet new <path_to_zip_template_file`
`dotnet new --install <path_to_zip_template_file`

The first command crashed with:

> No templates found matching `<path_to_zip_template_file>`

The second command crashed with:

> `<path_to_zip_template_file` is not supported

I'm probably doing something way off. Does anyone know what that might be?

Answer (score 0):

Unzip the `.zip`

then in your terminal, navigate to the template folder (it should contain a folder named `.template.config`)

Then run `dotnet new --install .\`

---

Alternatively, `dotnet new --install` also supports installing nuget packages `.nupkg`, which you can create following the steps here: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/cli-templates-create-template-package